# retrieve values from an json array in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

what will be the easiest way to retrive the "HydraulicPressure" and "FailedPickupsLastHr" values from the below json in logic app?

```
{
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "sensorarray",
      "type": "String",
      "value": "{\"ContentData\":{\"applicationId\":\"0db2345\",\"deviceId\":\"178\",\"enqueuedTime\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:22.386Z\",\"enrichments\":{},\"messageSource\":\"properties\",\"messageType\":\"devicePropertyReportedChange\",\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"FailedPickupsLastHr\",\"value\":42},{\"name\":\"HydraulicPressure\",\"value\":30.863390107917837}],\"schema\":\"default@v1\",\"templateId\":\"dtmi:z\"},\"Properties\":{\"iotcentral-application-id\":\"05\",\"iotcentral-message-source\":\"properties\",\"iotcentral-message-type\":\"devicePropertyReportedChange\",\"iotcentral-device-id\":\"1q9hn5l4xcl\",\"x-opt-sequence-number\":5663,\"x-opt-offset\":\"5307784\",\"x-opt-enqueued-time\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:28.046Z\",\"message-id\":{\"EncodeSize\":38},\"group-sequence\":0},\"SystemProperties\":{\"EnqueuedTimeUtc\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:28.046Z\",\"Offset\":\"5307784\",\"PartitionKey\":null,\"SequenceNumber\":5663}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load this definition as a new LogicApp into your tenant ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_Failed_Pickups_Last_Hr": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FailedPickupsLastHr",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": "@variables('Object')['ContentData']['properties'][0]['value']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Hydraulic_Pressure": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Hydraulic_Pressure": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "HydraulicPressure",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{variables('Object')['ContentData']['properties'][1]['value']}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Object",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": "@JSON(variables('Payload'))"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Payload": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Payload": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Payload",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "{\"ContentData\":{\"applicationId\":\"0db2345\",\"deviceId\":\"178\",\"enqueuedTime\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:22.386Z\",\"enrichments\":{},\"messageSource\":\"properties\",\"messageType\":\"devicePropertyReportedChange\",\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"FailedPickupsLastHr\",\"value\":42},{\"name\":\"HydraulicPressure\",\"value\":30.863390107917837}],\"schema\":\"default@v1\",\"templateId\":\"dtmi:z\"},\"Properties\":{\"iotcentral-application-id\":\"05\",\"iotcentral-message-source\":\"properties\",\"iotcentral-message-type\":\"devicePropertyReportedChange\",\"iotcentral-device-id\":\"1q9hn5l4xcl\",\"x-opt-sequence-number\":5663,\"x-opt-offset\":\"5307784\",\"x-opt-enqueued-time\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:28.046Z\",\"message-id\":{\"EncodeSize\":38},\"group-sequence\":0},\"SystemProperties\":{\"EnqueuedTimeUtc\":\"2022-09-17T14:27:28.046Z\",\"Offset\":\"5307784\",\"PartitionKey\":null,\"SequenceNumber\":5663}}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "ParameterTest1": {
                "defaultValue": "\"\"",
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

It will give you my answer in full and show you how to get to the values you're after.

The basic steps are ...

1. Initialize the initial JSON you have as a string.
2. Then convert that string to an object using the `json` expression
3. The last two steps involve expressions to extract the values you're after.

Basically, you need to parse the string value to an object and then evaluate it.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your response..but I am getting the input as a mesage from eventhub which of string type.So I am unbale to initialize a varibale of object type from the string values.Is there a way around?

Comment: You need to show the exact payload from event hub.  I've shown how to do that in my answer.  You need to be very clear on what the payload looks like.  Maybe show a screenshot just to be sure.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that helps.  Bottom line, a string can be converted to an object by using the `json` expression.  I think that's where you're going wrong.  Now I look at your JSON, I can see it's the definition for a variable, I've now provided the exact same scenario and example.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a detailed help...it worked !!

Comment: hi Skin...just wondering is there a way we can add a condition while initializing the values in the variable on a device id.. like there are many messages that are coming but i want to set my variable for a specific device id?

Comment: Look at the filter action in the data operations group.  If that doesn't work, I've built a connector and just need to finish another operation (that I'm working through) and that would be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot skin! let me try and also do update me once the connector is avaiable!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, you can similarly do it for your json array as below:
Firstly, select initialize variable step and then set it with below json example :

```
[{
"variables": 
    {
        "name": "sensorarray",
        "type": "String"
    }
}]
```

Then, select the **SELECT** step
And then select the varaible you want from array and then get it with using item as below:

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

Try to update your array as the given example and try the above steps you will get the output as above.

Comment: the json i am getting from source can only be initialized as string type it seems..not abe to initialize the variable as array type